# Removing all \n\r characters from a node XSLT?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

wondered if you could help me please? I have node in xml that is as followed

> $LOG: 08880xbpnd $
> fhdsafidsfsd
> df
> sd
> fsd
> f
> sd
> fsd

I was wondering is there anyway to make all the text go on to one line so that it then can be passsed through to a javascript function? so it would turn out like this

> $LOG: 08880xbpnd $fhdsafidsfsddfsdfsdfsdfsd

Comment: Unfortunately, the normalize-space() function (used in the answer of andynormancx) does more than deleting newlines. It deletes all leading and trailing whitespace and it replaces any group of inner contigious whitespace with a single space character. A better solution is to use translate()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Unfortunately, the [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-normalize-space) function (used in the answer of andynormancx) does more than deleting newlines**.

It deletes all leading and trailing whitespace and **it replaces any group of inner contigious whitespace with a single space character**.

In many cases we want to deleteonly one type of a white-space character (as in the current case -- new lines (CR+LF is automatically normalized on reading by the XML parser to just LF).

**The correct and safe way to do so is by using the standard XPath [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-translate) function**:

```
translate(., '&#xA;', '')
```

returns a string obtained from the string-value of the current node in which any newline character is deleted.

**Here is an example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of 
     select="translate(.,'&#xA;','')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on this source XML document**:

```
<t>
$LOG: 08880xbpnd $
"embedded    blanks    must    stay"
df
sd
fsd
f
sd
fsd
</t>
```

**The result is on one line only, as required, and all embedded spaces are left intact**:

```
<t>$LOG: 08880xbpnd $"embedded    blanks    must    stay"dfsdfsdfsdfsd</t>
```

Comment: +1 definitely a better solution, if you need the inner whitespace preserved.

Answer (score 7):

The [normalize-space()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063(VS.85).aspx) XPath function should do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, the normalize-space() function (used in the answer of andynormancx) does more than deleting newlines. 

It deletes all leading and trailing whitespace and it replaces any group of inner contigious whitespace with a single space character.

A better solution is to use translate()

Comment: Fair enough, but on the plus side the questions example didn't have any whitespace ;)