# Using the Translate function to remove newline characters in xml, but how do I ignore certain tags?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath

Following the question- [Removing all \n\r characters from a node XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552762/removing-all-n-r-characters-from-a-node-xslt) that looks to be solved, I am using this solution, but stumbled across this scenario-

What if we do not want the new line characters to be replaced in all the nodes.
eg- Certain nodes like Description, Instructions are meant to store new lines if the user entered them on the webpage.

```
<T>
    <Name>Translate test</Name>
    <AlternateId>testid1</AlternateId>
    <Description>Translate test</Description>
    <Instructions>there is a new line between line1 and line2
    line1-asdfghjkl
    line2-asdfghjkl</Instructions>
    <Active>1</Active>
</T>
```

After using translate(.,'
',''), this is how the xml looks like now:

```
<T>
    <Name>Translate test</Name>
    <AlternateId>testid1</AlternateId>
    <Description>Translate test</Description>
    <Instructions>there is a new line between line1 and line2line1-asdfghjklline2-asdfghjkl</Instructions>
    <Active>1</Active>
</T>
```

I have >100 such tags that I don't want to be translated. Is there a way to ignore the translation of such unwanted tags?
Any timely help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ashish K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually such a task is solved by starting with a template that copies nodes unchanged

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now you can add templates to transform the elements you want e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="Description | Instructions">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#10;', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course you would need to list all element names you want to be transformed in the `match` attribute but you don't have to spell out the names of elements you don't want to be transformed.

Comment: Yes... this is much more elegant solution. I don't know why I didn't use identity transformation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter elements in match attributes

```
<xsl:template match="*[name() = 'Instructions']/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xA;','')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which means something like "only in Instruction element replace newline characters".

Edit:

You could make a external helper xml file containing names of elements indended for replacing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Replace>
    <Description />
    <Instructions />
</Replace>
```

Load it into a variable by `document()` function

```
<xsl:variable name="elementsForReplacing" select="document('replaceNames.xml')/Replace/*" />
```

Then just check for presence in this variable for decision if replacing should be done.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="name(..)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$elementsForReplacing[name() = $elementName]">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&#xA;','')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm afraid the nodes are just too many to do that. I'm talking about hundreds of nodes.What if I want all the multiline textboxes to retain the newline character and the rest to be replaced?

Comment: You could make an external file with names of elements to be replaced and then check each element against this file. I improved my answer.