# XPath for an element that follows some specific paragraph text nested in a div?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to select the text "Part Sun, Sun" and "Herb", "Houseplant" from the html below.

The `<div class="specifics">` has more of these "row" divs and the text I'm interested in always comes after certain paragraph tags containing specific text like "Light:", and "Type:" below.

Edit: To clarify out of all the "value" divs I'm only interested in ones that have specific "names". So I want to check the text of paragraphs nested inside `<div class="name">` elements and if it's what I'm interested in then select the text inside the subsequent `<div class="value">` element.

```
<div class="specifics">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      <p>Light:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <p>Part Sun, Sun</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="name">
      <p>Type:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <p>
        <a href="https://www.bhg.com/gardening/plant-dictionary/herb/">Herb</a>, <a href="https://www.bhg.com/gardening/plant-dictionary/houseplant/">Houseplant</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...more rows...
</div>
```

I've tried this (using Scrapy):

```
trait = response.xpath("//div[@class='specifics']")
trait.xpath(".//div[@class='row']/div[@class='name']/p[text()='Light:']/../../div[@class='value']/p/text()[normalize-space()]")
```

The first line is ok but the second one is returning `\n                \n`

Apologies for poor editing originally, below is what the paragraph element actually looks like.

Second Edit: There are a bunch of empty lines and when I select just /p without text() I still get back just a bunch of \n without any of the text? Tried normalize-space as above.

```
  <p>




                                            Part Sun, 






                                            Sun



  </p>
```

Comment: In future, plz take the time to format the code. In this example in particular it's important for us to see the tree easily.

Comment: Show how you tried.

Comment: Just noticed in your question you've worded it that you need response of: "Part Sun, Sun" and "Herb", "Houseplant". I assume you meant "Part Sun, Sun" and "Herb, Houseplant", where Herb and Houseplant are returned as a single match in one string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the elements you need, you can do something like this:
`/div[@class='specifics']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='value']/p`

Adding `/text()` on the end will grab the `Part Sun, Sun` in your first row, but because your second row has additional nested elements in it, that text won't be picked up.

Instead you can use `/string()` which will also extract text from children. `/div[@class='specifics']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='value']/p/string()`

If you also need to strip out whitespace then you can use either `normalize-whitespace()` or `translate(input, charsToReplace, replacement)`.

- `/div[@class='specifics']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='value']/p/normalize-space(string())`. Using [this tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) I get output of `String='Part Sun, Sun'` and `String='Herb, Houseplant'`
- `/div[@class='specifics']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='value']/p/translate(string(), '&#xA;', '')` where `&#xA;` is the newline character, but you could also add [others characters](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/handler.asp?/xsllist/200107/post61340.html) you need removing. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553475/725626)

Comment: Hi thanks!! I tried out what you suggested and I appear to be getting the paragraph element I want but not all of the text just line breaks? I edited my post with some more details.

Comment: Yes you're getting the `\n` because that's the encoded line breaks in the HTML. You may want to look at stripping those out somehow. Should be able to "Google" something that'll help :)

Comment: @whale-b see my updated answer for whitespace removal options